# Xamarin Forms - merge resources

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am having an issue accessing a resource defined in app.xaml in a merge resource dictionary.  How can I fix this?

Here is an example...

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:MyApp.Resources"
                x:Class="MyApp.App"
                >
    <Application.Resources>
        
        <Color x:Key="PrimaryColor">#00458c</Color>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <resources:IconResources />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**IconResources.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    xmlns:font="clr-namespace:MyApp.Resources"
                    xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:MyApp.Resources"
                    x:Class="MyApp.Resources.IconResources">

    <Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="WellTestsIcon">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" />
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Static font:IconFont.Flask}" />
    </Style>
    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This results in the error 'StaticResource not found for key PrimaryColor'.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend moving your color definition into its own dedicated ResourceDictionary (in this example Colors.xaml). Having each type of resource in their own dictionary seems to be the most scalable option when managing different types of resources.

I tested the following code in a sample project for both using the colors directly and within the Style you defined in IconResources.xaml

**Colors.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    x:Class="App14.Colors">
    <Color x:Key="PrimaryColor">#AA00458c</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**IconResources.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App14"
                    x:Class="App14.IconResources">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <local:Colors/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="WellTestsIcon">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**App.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App14"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App14.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <local:Colors/>
                <local:IconResources/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Some Test ContentPage**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App14.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" 
            Text="ColorCheck" TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"/>
        <Label HorizontalOptions="" 
            Text="StyleCheck" Style="{StaticResource WellTestsIcon}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: FYI, there has to be code behind files for separate resource dictionaries, [additional details are here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63399697/185123).