# Styles that are based upon other styles that span multiple files

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I use [Style Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/inheritance) w/ multiple files?  I've been able to utilize [Stand-alone resource dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#stand-alone-resource-dictionaries) but if a child style is `BasedUpon` a style in another file it isn't working.

In the example below, the `ListView` will have the specified `SeparatorColor` but not the `BackgroundColor` from the `BasedUpon` style.

*BaseStyles.xaml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <Color x:Key="LightPrimaryColor">LightPink</Color>
    <Color x:Key="DarkPrimaryColor">DarkGreen</Color>
    <Style x:Key="BaseColorStylePrimary" TargetType="View">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightPrimaryColor}, Dark={StaticResource DarkPrimaryColor}}" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

*SomeChildStyles.xaml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="ListViewStyleBasedOn"
           TargetType="ListView"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseColorStylePrimary}">
        <Setter Property="SeparatorColor"
                Value="{AppThemeBinding Light=Orange, Dark=Red}" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

*App.xaml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="StyleInheritance.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="BaseStyles.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="SomeChildStyles.xaml" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

It looks like they [made some changes a few years ago](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/better-resource-organization-xamarin-forms/) to achieve what I'm trying to do but when [they introduced `AppThemeBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes) it wasn't expanded to handle this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a code behind file w/ a call to `InitializeComponent()` to each separate resource file even though [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/better-resource-organization-xamarin-forms/#upcoming-resourcedictionary-improvements) says it is no longer required.
2. Don't use the [fancy clean way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/better-resource-organization-xamarin-forms/#upcoming-resourcedictionary-improvements) to remove extra code for defining `<ResourceDictionary>`'s

Updated *BaseStyles.xaml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    <!--change is here-->
                    x:Class="StyleInheritance.BaseStyles">
    <Color x:Key="LightPrimaryColor">LightPink</Color>
    <Color x:Key="DarkPrimaryColor">DarkGreen</Color>
    <Style x:Key="BaseColorStylePrimary" TargetType="View">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightPrimaryColor}, Dark={StaticResource DarkPrimaryColor}}" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

*BaseStyles.xaml.cs*

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace StyleInheritance
{
    public partial class BaseStyles : ResourceDictionary
    { public BaseStyles() { InitializeComponent(); } }
}
```

*SomeChildStyles.xaml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    <!--change is here-->
                    x:Class="StyleInheritance.SomeChildStyles">
    <Style x:Key="ListViewStyleBasedOn"
           TargetType="ListView"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseColorStylePrimary}">
        <Setter Property="SeparatorColor"
                Value="{AppThemeBinding Light=Orange, Dark=Red}" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Added *SomeChildStyles.xaml.cs*

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace StyleInheritance
{
    public partial class SomeChildStyles : ResourceDictionary
    { public SomeChildStyles() { InitializeComponent(); } }
}
```

*App.xaml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="StyleInheritance.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!--change is here-->
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="BaseStyles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="SomeChildStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

---

I've created a full [Sample project](https://github.com/spottedmahn/experiments-2020/tree/master/external-resources-xamarin) w/ some additional details in the readme.

Comment: You can mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Thanks @JackHua-MSFT - I plan to but you have to wait for a certain amount of time...

Answer (score 0):

Use [`MergedDictionaries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#merged-resource-dictionaries) to style with multiple files.

`App.xaml`:

```xml
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <!--Global Styles-->
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Base.xaml" />
      <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Child.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    ...
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

`Base.xaml` in folder `Styles`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--<?xaml-comp compile="true" ?>-->
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
  <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

`Child.xaml` in folder `Styles`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
  <Style x:Key="ChildStyle" TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Italic" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Sample XAML usage:

```xml
<Label Text="Background" Style="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"/>
<Label Text="Background+Italic" Style="{StaticResource ChildStyle}"/>
```

See also [Better Resource Organization in Xamarin.Forms](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/better-resource-organization-xamarin-forms/)

Edit:

To use a Xaml `ResourceDictionary` without a partial class (code behind class) (as indicated by the `x:Class` attribute), remove the code behind class `.xaml.cs` file and the `x:Class` attribute. Please note that the property `Build Action` should be `Embedded resource`.

The properties should be observed in the project file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Update="Styles\Child.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    <!--<Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>-->
  </EmbeddedResource>
  <EmbeddedResource Update="Styles\Base.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    <!--<Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>-->
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks Benl!  I was already using `MergedDictionaries` though.  [Apparently there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63399697/185123) are a few undocumented gotchas